# How to execute a function before and after the script is loaded in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a requirement where I want to execute one function just before the script is starting to load and also execute a function when the script is done loading and executing.

For example, I have the following script attached dynamically to the DOM.

```
var myScript = $('<div></div>').html("<script src='foo.js'></script>");
document.body.appendChild(myScript);
```

I want to execute a function `showSpinner()` before the script starts to load and execute.

and finally, want to execute the function `hideSpinner()` after the above script is done loading and executing the script.

Note:- I don't want to use any inline code or add a new script file to the server.

Comment: I think you want the [onload event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Comment: yes, it will work for the code to be executed after the script is loaded, but how to execute the code when script is just attached to dom?

Comment: Does `jQuery.getScript()` meet your needs?

Comment: Is there a difference between executing a function before attaching a script, and putting your function at the top of the attached script?

Comment: yes, i do have access to the code where it attaching the tag to the dom, so could we override the script to call the function before it gets executed.